# "semble (être) en passe de X": Whether to take a short cut, omitting "être"?

Tags: grammaire

> Néanmoins, le blockchain **semble** (***être***) **en passe de** devenir l’une des technologies les plus puissantes et les plus adaptées.

This question extends to a similar expression "semble (être) sur le point de X" for instance, but I have seen or heard native speakers around me include "être" almost as often as they drop it.

Which makes me wonder which is more common in speech as well as in writing? I mean, when "sembler" is followed by a prepositional phrase "en/sur/etc ..."?

Comment: On emploie aussi « chaîne de blocs », même avant que le [terme soit recommandé](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=blockchain&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) par  la commission d'enrichissement de la langue française.   https://bitcoin.org/fr/comment-ca-marche, https://www.ethereum-france.com/la-chaine-de-blocs-nest-pas-immuable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it strongly depends on whether the speaker consider that the expression includes *être*. It you consider it's a verbal semi-auxiliary *être en passe de*, then *semble être* is correct, if you consider it's an adverbial construction *en passe de*, then you wouldn't include *être* because it's entirely redundant with *sembler*.

Clearly the variation indicates usage is not settled on this issue.

Comment: Hi. What do you think of: "Tu ***as l'air d'être sur*** le point de faire" vs  "Tu ***as l'air sur*** le point de faire"?

Comment: It's a little harder to assess it because I don't lean either way on *être en passe de*, but on *sur le point de* I lean strongly toward dropping the *être*, but that seems the less popular usage. It might well depends on how hardline you are about "omit needless words".